# How to Drag and Drop between two lists in React Native?

Tags: drag-and-drop, react-native, react-native-ios, trello

I am trying to create a Drag and Drop between two flat list like Kanban Drag and Drop Board or Trello Board.

I have checked some repositories, but they all are available in ReactJs. I want them in React Native.

Please help me with this.
Here's a link for [ReactJs Version](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about)

I want something with long press. User selects item on long press and then move that item from one list to another without moving original item. Just a copy of original item will move.

Comment: I found this [repository](https://github.com/lesniakania/react-native-draggable-board) it may help you, its a scrollable board component with sortable columns and draggable rows.

Comment: I want something with long press. User select items on long press and then move that item from one list to another without moving original item. Just a copy of original item will move.

Comment: @GeekHack any other success here?